# select n posts per category in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In my home page I show different posts from different categories.
My current implementation is to call query_posts many times (once per category)

**How can I use *one query* to pull out the data?**

### My tries

1 - this method works(ignore the ugly very long sql,I have many categories...)
Thanks the post:  http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

```
( SELECT * 
  FROM `wp_posts` p,`wp_term_relationships` rel 
  WHERE rel.object_id = p.ID 
   AND rel.term_taxonomy_id = '3' 
  ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
  LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL 
( SELECT * 
  FROM `wp_posts` p,`wp_term_relationships` rel 
  WHERE rel.object_id = p.ID 
    AND rel.term_taxonomy_id = '4' 
  ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
  LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: @ajreal (SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` p,`wp_term_relationships` rel WHERE rel.object_id = p.ID AND rel.term_taxonomy_id = '3' ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` p,`wp_term_relationships` rel WHERE rel.object_id = p.ID AND rel.term_taxonomy_id = '4' ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 2)

Comment: Hi,@Zohaib I search around and find this solution,it works.Isn't it a little ugly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM wp_term_relationships rel
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT p.*, rel2.* 
  FROM wp_posts p
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rel2
          ON (rel2.object_id = p.ID) 
  WHERE rel2.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
  ORDER BY p.post_date DESC 
  LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0 ) i ON (i.object_id = rel.object_id)
WHERE rel.term_taxonomy_id IN ('3','4')
ORDER BY i.term_taxonomy_id ASC, i.post_date DESC
```

Comment: Using this sql I get this:#1054 - Unknown column 'rel.term_taxonomy_id' in 'where clause'